# Trim - De qué formas puedo cortar un texto?

Tags: java

Tengo esta función que me corta un texto:

```
public String cortarTexto(String texto, int size) {

        try {
            if(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(texto).isEmpty())
                return texto;
            if(size<=0)
                return texto;

            if(texto.lenght()>size) {
                texto = texto.substring(0, size);
            }
            return texto;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Para hacerlo más sencillo, qué podría emplear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad no es necesario usar la clase `StringUtils`.

Lo que deseas es realizar el corte de la cadena cuando:

- `size` es mayor a 0
- `texto` no es una cadena vacía.
- `texto` es mayor a `size`

Esto podría reducir el código:

```
public String cortarTexto(String texto, int size) {
        //Retorna el mismo texto si text tiene una cadena vacía
        //o size es menor a 1
        if(texto.trim().isEmpty() || size<=0)
            return texto; 
        //Si la longitud de texto es mayor a size
        //Realiza el corte de la cadena,
        //de otra forma regresa una cadena vacia "".
        return (texto.length() > size)?texto.substring(0, size):"";
}
```

Agregaría una validación para el caso en el cual `texto` tenga valor `null`:

```
public String cortarTexto(String texto, int size) {
        if(texto == null || texto.trim().isEmpty() || size<=0)
            return ""; 
        return (texto.length() > size)?texto.substring(0, size):"";
}
```

Comment: Me ayudo mucho!, muchas gracias!!